# Google SSID cookie and TOR

Tags: network-configuration, cookies

[image: Gmail cookies]

If you view the linked image you will see that when I log into gmail google stores a cookie called SSID on my system. Is it possible that their javascript requests the SSID of my Wi-Fi network from the network? If I am logged into a hotspot with a distinctive name such as "L33T H4CK3R UNIVERSITY SECURE WI-FI" or "Manufacturer-DeFaUlt-HOmE-rOUtEr-nAmE1234x599" this could be a security issue that allows someone to deduce my true IP address even if I am using TOR or a VPN. For instance, google has a Wi-Fi hotspot map; they could use that map to figure out my true IP and true location from my Wi-Fi network name.

Could someone recommend libraries I could look at or an approach I could take to program a Firefox or Chrome plugin that would spoof the Wi-Fi network name and other information that is passed to Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

SSID is not abbreviated only as **S**ervice **S**et **ID**entifier, it also referenced as **S**ecure **S**ession **ID**entifier, depending on context. Try to take a look at it's actual value to determine if there is a security issue. Just using a `SSID` as a cookie name is defenately not harming neither security, nor privacy

Comment: Yes clearly SSID could stand for anything. Google could also use a cookie called ABCD to store my SSID name. What worries me is the possibility that google may be collecting system level information from javascript to compromise the anonymity provided by my VPN. I wonder if you could help me find a resource I could use to research how (if?) Javascript can make OS API calls to get information about my system such as what operating system I am using, the SSID, or even information about the file directory. If my home folder is Joe_Sixpack_Laptop can a javascript request that information?

Comment: @JohnMiller the JS capabilities are highly-dependent on a browser you're using and it's version. If you're concerned about the data leaks you've mentioned upstrings - use a blank VM isolated from your host PC and launch browser inside it : it will see NOTHING except a gateway 192.168.0.1 and a blackhole-like network card that attaches your VM to Tor as a router. No proxies, no real DNS addresses, NOTHING

Comment: Thanks so much! What is a blank VM? do you mean one that I only use for the purpose of surfing the web anonymously? How can I isolate it from my host pc? For example if I installed linux on VirtualBox then just opened that up would that be sufficient? Or are there other steps I should take?

Comment: @JohnMiller Correct! And by it's "blankness" I presume that NOTHING except an OS and a Web browser is installed on it. To isolate a VM from a host is quite easy: use a VM that has only one network **host-only** interface, so no NAT or Bridge networking at all! And route it's traffic through Tor's TransPort+DNS. It's a piece of cake in firewall rules.

Comment: I have been doing some research on my own, and most blogs I have read (for instance: http://christophermaier.name/blog/2010/09/01/host-only-networking-with-virtualbox/) seem to suggest that I have to set up  one Network Adapter on VBox with NAT to access the internet at all. Then I can set up a second network adaptor with Host Only so that I can ssh into my virtual machine; I don't want to ssh into my virtual machine, though. Will I still have a "blank" machine with just an NAT adapter? it seems superfluous to run a host-only interface if this is mainly to access the vm from host

Comment: @JohnMiller No! **only** host-only : NAT can be used to do some things like WebRTC usage etc... Do the blackhole jail for this VM - and the network **is** a layer of isolation/line of defense

Comment: It is saying on most blogs that I need to set up a NAT connection to use a proxy on the host os. Why do you think NAT is less secure? I read the VirtualBox manual, and their NAT setting seems to be supplying a wired virtual network "blackbox" like you suggested.

Comment: You *must avoid* proxy! If your host is Linux - just use a firewall rules to route all the traffic through Tor. If your host is Windows - make another VM with Linux and make it a Tor node+router. If you need help - post your hw specs and software list, I'll be glad to help

Comment: I am planning to use a proprietary vpn service called private internet access. What exactly is the advantage of using host only over NAT? NAT is much easier to set up.

Comment: @JohnMiller in host-only mode you're locking the whole network part in **one** pipe that is routed explicitly through Tor via firewall. In NAT mode there's a possibility to contact the host and/or networks it's connected to.

Comment: Ok I am thinking of installing tor or proprietary vpn in linux virtual machine then turning off proprietary vpn for host os how does that sound?

Comment: I turned off my proxy though, and I still cannot access the internet when I use host-only network interface

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/787793/use-host-only-network-adapter-in-virtualbox from link: "Note that all interaction is between the host and the guest VMs, not the host's other networks, so you won't be able to access the internet via a host only connection, unless your host is setup to do routing. Have you tried the NAT mode instead?" So you are basically saying that I should create a host-only adapter then set up routing on host os? What if I just run tor on the guest os? How could it expose system level details of host os if packets are encrypted prior to leaving guest os?

Comment: @JohnMiller usually host-only network contains an IP address for the host itself too, and - for example in case of VirtualBox - sometimes you **can't** avoid connecting physical host by IP to it. And - some services are created, some restarted - and the service can listen to the port number, not to the particular IP(actually, it's a reasonable default for many of services). And here goes the leak *possibility*... Post your h/w and s/w stack - I can help you if you wish